# Can't create Amazon EKS Cluster with Gitlab

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab

I'am trying to add kubernetes cluster to my Gitlab repository using Amazon EKS. Authentication step is going successful, but on cluster creating via Gitlab step I getting following troubles:

- Gitlab can't receive IAM Roles and I can't pick them.
- Gitlab can't receive regions from AWS account.

[Form errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jqz3.jpg)

I guess AWS account have enough roles to show, I have roles with full IAM access.
Then I decided to check browser dev tools and found that there are some errors with accessing Amazon services.

Error pattern: `Refused to connect to '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' <URL> <URL> <URL> <URL> <URL> <URL> <URL>".`

[Console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im5AG.jpg)

I thought this is a problem with adblocker extension and I tried to use clean browser, but I got same throubles.